# NotificationCompatBuilder instance for each Notification Channel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm trying to create two different notifications with two different importance/priority levels. Do I have to create two different instances of a NotificationCompatBuilder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL ID")
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL ID 2")
```

since the builder accepts a specific Channel ID as we can see in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 8.0 (API 26) all notifications must be assigned to a `NotificationChannel`. The `NotificationChannel` controls the priority of the notifications assigned to it with the `importance` parameter of the `NotificationChannel`.

Now, when creating the `Notification` via the `Builder` You will have the option to use the `setPriority` method. When it comes to Android 8.0 and later, calls to `setPriority` will have no effect on the `Notification`'s importance. If You are targetting API < 26, then You will have to use `setPriority` no matter what the `importance` of the `NotificationChannel` of that `Notification` is.

Now, the answer to Your question is - it depends.

If You are targetting only API >= 26, then You want to use `NotificationCompat.Builder`s **with different channel IDs** as only `NotifcationChannels` control the priority.

If You are targetting only API < 26, You will just want to use the `setPriority` method on the `Builder` and **only one** `Builder` would be enough in that case (but using two, with different `channelId`s would also be fine).

If You are targetting APIs that are both >= 26 and < 26 then You should use the approach as if You were targetting API >= 26 while additionally calling `setPriority` on the `Builder` (You can wrap the call to `setPriority` in the version check). This approach would require You to have **two `Builder`s** with different `channelId`s.

Comment: Thank you on your detailed answer :)